# Vector/ Array of zoo objects in R

Tags: r, vector, time-series, zoo

I have the following time series:

```
library(lubridate)
library (zoo)
ts1 <- "f,c
    1,19/11/2014 12:00,0.01
    2,19/11/2014 13:00,0.01
    3,20/11/2014 15:00,0.01
    4,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
    5,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01  
    6,20/11/2014 19:00,0.01  
    7,20/11/2014 22:00,0.20  
    8,20/11/2014 23:00,0.03
    9,21/11/2014 16:00,0.01
    10,21/11/2014 17:00,0.01"

z <- read.zoo(text = ts1, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")
```

I would like to create a vector/ array `z2` of `zoo` object so that for instance:

```
z2[1]<-window(z, start = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 15:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 16:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
z2[2]<-window(z, start = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 17:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 23:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
z2[3]<-window(z, start = parse_date_time("21/11/2014 16:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("21/11/2014 17:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
```

So I'll be able to use z2[1], z2[2] and z2[3] as every zoo objects.

Comment: `z2 <- list()` then do your assignments to  `z2[[1]], z2[[2]] , z2[[3]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @42:

```
z2 <- list()
z2[[1]]<-window(z, start = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 15:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 16:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
z2[[2]]<-window(z, start = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 17:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 23:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
z2[[3]]<-window(z, start = parse_date_time("21/11/2014 16:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("21/11/2014 17:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
```